# Is there a way to record video of parallet tests in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

Im using selenium with python 2.7
running parallel test using pytest.

while running the tests the broesers are in background.
is there a way to have a video recored each driver?

Comment: Hi Dana, could you elaborate better your question please?

Comment: i'd like video recording of my selenium testing